# LeadingMarginSpan: Dynamic value returned from getLeadingMargin (why getLeadingMargin is being called before drawLeadingMargin?)

Tags: android, formatting, textview, spannablestring

This question is about `LeadingMarginSpan` interface.

**The goal:** I want to return a dynamic value from `getLeadingMargin()`, calculated depending on the height of text. **But** the text height can be detected only during `drawLeadingMargin()` call.

**Problem 1:** As documentation says:

> `drawLeadingMargin()` is called **before** the margin has been
>   adjusted by the value returned by `getLeadingMargin()`.

But that's not true. I tried to debug it, and I saw that `getLeadingMargin()` is being called twise before `drawLeadingMargin()`, and one time after:

```
System.out: getLeadingMargin
System.out: getLeadingMargin
System.out: drawLeadingMargin
System.out: getLeadingMargin
```

So, during the first 2 calls I still don't know the height of the text, so I have to return `0` as leading margin. Then (during `drawLeadingMargin()` call) I save the text height, and from this time I can return non-zero value from `getLeadingMargin()`. But this causes the second problem.

**Problem 2:** If at the first 2 calls `getLeadingMargin()` returns `0`, but then (after `drawLeadingMargin()`) it returns `>0`, then the text is being truncated right:

[image]

*PS: Due to performance reasons I don't want to call `requestLayout()` one more time after text is built.*

---

*Source code*

**LMarginSpan**

```
class LMarginSpan implements LeadingMarginSpan
{
    float lineHeight = 0f;

    @Override
    public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir, int top, int baseline, int bottom, CharSequence text, int start, int end, boolean first, Layout layout) {
        System.out.println("drawLeadingMargin");
        lineHeight = p.getFontSpacing();
    }

    @Override
    public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {
        System.out.println("getLeadingMargin");
        return (int) lineHeight;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
findViewById(R.id.Btn1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello world!");
        sb.setSpan(new LMarginSpan(), 0, sb.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Txt1)).setText(sb);
    }
});
```

Comment: see [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/text/Layout.java#349)

Comment: @pskink You didn't answer at all. In the code part you mentioned there are 2 calls: `drawLeadingMargin` and then `getLeadingMargin`. But how does it happen that `getLeadingMargin` is being called twice before `drawLeadingMargin`? (see the problem 1)

Comment: because `getLeadingMargin` is first called twice from other place, use `Thread.dumpStack` to see from where

Comment: @pskink I know where it is being called from. The place is `StaticLayout#generate()`. But this is not the answer too. I should prevent this behavior somehow. Maybe by using DynamicLayout instead of Static. Or anything else. I'm just asking for options.

Comment: ok, in other words: what actually do you want to achieve with your custom `LeadingMarginSpan` ?

Comment: @pskink I've written my goal in the question. In a nutshell, I want to get the text size in the moment when `getLeadingMargin()` is being called. But there are 2 problems. I discribed them as well.

Comment: leading margin is in x axis, you are talking about the line height (`getFontSpacing` operates in y axis), it makes a little sense so, and that's why it seems you get that interface wrong, without the real purpose i cannot understand what you really want to do with your span

Comment: @pskink Oh man. X axis, Y axis, no matter. I see that you cannot help me with it. I'll edit a question a bit to make it more clear, and may be somebody will give me some thoghts later. But thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass TextView to your custom Spannable to get Paint from it. For example:

```
private Paint paint;

public CustomSpannable(TextView textView) {
    paint = textView.getPaint();
}

public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {
    return mPaint.measureText("text"));
}
```